# Formatting an existing json to correct json format in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I've a json file, and there is a comma in the end of JSON object. How to remove the last comma of Item2?
Opening this file in the notepad++ having json viewer plugin/Format json removes the commas from Item1, Item2 and last json object.

Does PowerShell support reading this json and format properly like notepad++ does?
Found this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2

Did not find any options in ConvertTo-Json to format the json given below. And write same json again in correct format.

```
{
    "Name": "SampleName",
    "Cart": [
        {
            "Item1": "ItemOne",
            
        },
        {
            "Item2": "ItemTwo",
            
        },
    ]
}
```

Expected json output

```
{
    "Name": "SampleName",
    "Cart": [
        {
            "Item1": "ItemOne"
        },
        {
            "Item2": "ItemTwo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No, it is simply an invalid [`Json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string (only peeking/poking directly into the string might correct this, which I would discourage you to do). You should investigate how you created the sting/file as no respected `Json` serializer should allow this to happen.

Comment: This json is coming from buggy script written in PowerShell. Will try to fix it in original file writer.

Comment: If you can post that script, we might be able to help you

Comment: Thanks @Theo Fixed in the script however I got answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the third-party module [**newtonsoft.json**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json)

Then the cmdlet `ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft` will accept this *malformatted* JSON file.
Once converted to an object you can convert it back to a json valid string

```
$a = @"
{
    "Name": "SampleName",
    "Cart": [
        {
            "Item3": "ItemOne",
            
        },
        {
            "Item2": "ItemTwo",
            
        },
    ]
}
"@
$a | ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft | ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft
```